# How to play a video in android which is store in php server

Tags: php, android, web-services

How to play a video in android from a php server, I store the video on a php server this is the link where is video file stored - [video](http://livedeals.co.in/upload/photos/movie.mp4) please help me for this problem...

This is android side code..

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {
int position;
private VideoView v;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position");
    setContentView(R.layout.act_video);

    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("livedeals.co.in/upload/photos/movie.mp4");
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Play Mp4 video from server android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510473/play-mp4-video-from-server-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that your video file must be compatible with Android. You can check compatibility here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Try this code :

```
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {
// Declare variables
ProgressDialog pDialog;
VideoView videoview;
int position;`enter code here`
// Insert your Video URL
String VideoURL = "livedeals.co.in/upload/photos/movie.mp4";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// Get the layout from video_main.xml
setContentView(R.layout.act_video);
 position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position");
// Find your VideoView 
videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
// Execute StreamVideo AsyncTask
// Create a progressbar
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(VideoActivity.this);
// Set progressbar title
pDialog.setTitle("Video Streaming");
// Set progressbar message
pDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
pDialog.setCancelable(false);
// Show progressbar
pDialog.show();
try {
// Start the MediaController
MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
VideoActivity.this);
mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
// Get the URL from String VideoURL
Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
videoview.setVideoURI(video);
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
e.printStackTrace();
}
videoview.requestFocus();
videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
// Close the progress bar and play the video
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
pDialog.dismiss();
videoview.start();
}
});
}
}
```