# Android file download and read in our application only?

Tags: android, buffering

**I want my android application to read pdf and video from the server (like buffering) dont want to store in external file.**

Any referrence please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: download the video but save it encrypted , ta- daa!!

Comment: can you give any reference?

Comment: its is very simple you can use WebViewClient to navigate to the url contain pdf to view your pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read PDF file,

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
webView.addView(webView.getZoomControls());
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://myurl.com/demo.pdf");
```

buffer video from server, [Play Mp4 video from server android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510473/play-mp4-video-from-server-android)